# apps will not access microphone

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone 6.  I have tested the microphone and it works in google and voice recorder but does not work in any other browsers, messenger or siri.  I have checked privacy>microphone and it displays Google and voice recorder.  No other applications have requested to use the microphone.